# How to find the rotation based on a collision point in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, particles

I have two objects, where one is a hand and the other is a cube. When the hand touches the cube I get a contact point (Vector3) and spawns a Ring particle effect. However, the rotation of the particle is wrong, because I want the ring to be parralel to the side of the cube the hand touches.

The cube can rotate so calculating the ring rotation gets tricky. Here I try to calculate the rotation based on the normal of the collision point, but the ring still doesn't spawn correctly (almost seems to spawn randomly).

```
private void StartParticles(Vector3 pos, Transform parent, Color color, Vector3 normal)
    {
        ParticleSystem pSystem = Instantiate(ps2, pos, Quaternion.identity, parent);
        var main = pSystem.main;
        main.startColor = color;
        // start rotation
        //.eulerAngles;
        Vector3 rot = Quaternion.LookRotation(normal).eulerAngles;
        main.startRotationX = rot.x;
        main.startRotationY = rot.y;
        main.startRotationZ = rot.z;
        pSystem.Play();
        Destroy(pSystem, 3.0f);
    }
```

This is an example where the line represents the collision, the square represents the cube, and what I want is the rings to be parallel to the side of the cube the hand touches. Since the cube can rotate the start rotation values (Euler : [x, y, z]) for the particle system need to be found dynamically.

[image]

Comment: Maybe just transform.lookat the cube + add standard rotation given the lookat rotation

Comment: what would the standard rotation part be?

Comment: you'd find that out after the first time you had the particles look at the cube. You'd always need to rotate them the same angle to make them parallel ( I'm assuming they'll always lie directly on one of the axes of the cube as you say they have to be parallel to a side). For example sometimes text needs to be rotated 180 degrees even after it's set to look at the camera in order for you to read it correctly. I may have the setup wrong in my head though, could you post a picture of what you want and what is wrong?

Comment: i added a little sketch, which i hope helps visualize my problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//TODO: introduce instance reusability/pooling
void StartParticles ( Vector3 pos , Transform parent , Color color , Vector3 normal )
{
    //instantiate:
    ParticleSystem pSystem = Instantiate(
        ps2 ,
        pos ,
        Quaternion.LookRotation( normal ) ,
        parent
    ).GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();

    //assertions:
    UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsTrue(
        pSystem.main.simulationSpace == ParticleSystemSimulationSpace.Local ,
        "This will only work when simulation space is set to local"
    );

    //initialize modules:
    var main = pSystem.main;
    main.startColor = color;

    //play:
    pSystem.Play();

    //queue destroy:
    Destroy( pSystem , 3.0f );
}
```

Comment: I'm using a custom particle with a 2D texture. Setting the rotation of the particle system, in this case, doesn't rotate the particles. The only way I can change the particle rotation is by changing the startRotationX, startRotationY, startRotationZ components of the particle system.

Comment: "Custom particle with 2d texture" seems pretty standard, most particles are of this type. Are you sure Simulation Space is set to local here?

Comment: Simulation space is local is the particle system settings in the Editor.

Comment: Maybe make sure your particle system works in this space then. It would be a breeze if that was the case. Especially when that cube moves then you want those particles to follow it around and inherit it's rotations